# Forecasting unevenly spaced time series data

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am fairly new to this field and I would like to get some help/advices. Any help would be much appreciated!

I am currently doing a forecasting project with time series data. However, it does not contain any weekend/holiday data. My goal is to predict the future value on a specific date. For example, with given data from 2000-present, I would like to predict the value of 2023-05-01. I tried creating some plots and use the zoo package. However, I am unsure how to approach this unevenly spaced data. Can someone provide me with some ideas of what model I should try? Btw, I am using R for this project. Thank you all so much!

Comment: Please provide your coding effort and give us a sample of your actual data.

Comment: Not my area, but I do know there are a number of articles on using unevenly spaced observations--on earth the only possible kind, really--of variable stars to extract their light curves by Grant Foster (better known as the blogger tamino in climate circles). See his book https://www.amazon.com/Analyzing-Light-Curves-Practical-Guide/dp/B01MPXR1WP

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33796/is-there-any-gold-standard-for-modeling-irregularly-spaced-time-series) for irregularly spaced time series. But if you are only missing weekends your time series is not really irregularly spaced. Stock prices, for instance, fall into this category and are commonly modelled using the typical ts methods such as ARIMA. See [this](https://otexts.com/fpp2/index.html).

Comment: Treat this as a regularly spaced series where the ith point is at time i or if it is good enough to consider monthly data then you can make it regularly spaced by aggregating to the month.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with @jhoward that this is missing data, not unevenly spaced (like timestamped data). So you can interpolate the missing data. Maybe this helps for an overview of the possible techniques: [4-techniques-to-handle-missing-values-in-time-series-data](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-techniques-to-handle-missing-values-in-time-series-data-c3568589b5a8)